# How to display array values in dropdownlist using react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to display all months in dropdown using react js. Below is my code .I have used moments to fetch all 12 months. I am getting value in console but not in my dropdown.

To display the dropdown values want to use the . 
I have used that also. I don't know where I went wrong. Could any one can help me with this? Thanks in advance.

```
const fareMon = () => {
      const months = [];
      const monthList = moment.months();
      months.push(<option value={monthList} />);
      console.log('MONTHS123', monthList);
      return months;
};
return (
<div className={styles.formClm2}>
    <Form.Group className={styles.formGroup}>
        <Form.Label>{t('PaymentPage.lblExpiry')}</Form.Label>
        <div className="double">
            <Form.Control required as="select" name="startDate">
                <option value="">Months</option>
                {fareMon()}
            </Form.Control>
        </div>
    </Form.Group>
</div> )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const fareMon = () => {
  const monthList = moment.months();
  const months = monthList.map(item => (
    <option key={item} value={item}>{item}</option> 
  ));
  console.log('MONTHS123', monthList);
  return months;
};
```

you need to iterate the `monthsList` and map each month to a `<option>`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the array of months and set the value in the form controls options element.

Something like this, something simplified.

```
<Form.Control required as="select" name="startDate">
  {months.map(month => (<option key={month.id} value={month.value}>{month.label}</option>))}
</Form.Control>
```

Key points:

- Iterate over a data source of some description.
- Ensure each option has a `key` prop

Answer (score 1):

`moment.months()` returns an array containing the months name, you don't need to create a new array.

You have to map over the array inside the `Select` to show up the options.

**Example:**

```
const fareMon = () => {
    const monthList = moment.months();
    return monthList;
};
return (
    <div className={styles.formClm2}>
        <Form.Group className={styles.formGroup}>
            <Form.Label>{t('PaymentPage.lblExpiry')}</Form.Label>
            <div className="double">
                <Form.Control required as="select" name="startDate">
                    <option value="">Months</option>
                    {fareMon().map( month => (<option key={month} value={month}>{month}</option>))}
                </Form.Control>
            </div>
        </Form.Group>
    </div>
)
```